# "Connection timed out" error on a deploy with deployment module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Locally deploying content between two site instances works fine.
It's when moving one instance to a remote server that gives me the following error message:

```
Module : login
Description : Remote user
Result : Error
Message : Connection timed out
```

My apache access log entries are:

```
./node_operations/deploy_now/86 HTTP/1.1" 302
./admin/build/deploy/logs/details/6 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Deployment module version: 6.x-1.x-dev
Service module version: 6.x-2.2

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably firewall is blocking if you are seeing timeout.  You can fire up telnet on the dev box and test that you can actually connect to the target over port 80 - since deployment module uses xmlrpc to push content.  If all is working there you can check the Drupal watchdog logs.